# Formulas inserted into excel via vba from ms access do not activate when trying to reimport their calculated value

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I have written some code that plugs excel formulas exctracted from one file and stored in a db into a new excel file. Unfortunately those forumlas do not activate after being inserted and thus I receive an error when trying to import the value of those cells back into access. I tried to force calculation in excel using:

```
xlApp.Calculate
xlSheet.Calculate
xlApp.CalculateFull
xlApp.CalculateFullRebuild
```

which has no effect. It also does not work when using the button on the excel ribbon itself. I have also tried to set the cell format manually using:

```
xlSheet.Range(rstZutaten!XLCell).Offset(0, 1).NumberFormat = "0.0000"
```

Which has also not worked. The formula string inserts just fine into the excel file, it just doesnt activate and calculate the value of the cell. I can activate the cells by clicking on them and pressing enter etc. manually in the file but I want to do that in vba instead. Not sure where exactly the error is so I would appreciate any help. The code is quite long. The error occurs at

```
        rsRes!Wert = xlSheet.Range("F" & i).Value
```

Here the full code:

```
Private Sub Befehl8_Click()

'Declare variables
Dim xlApp As Object
Dim xlWB As Object
Dim xlSheet As Object
Dim rsRes As DAO.recordset     'rs of temp table (Output)
Dim rsZwi As DAO.recordset     'rs of temp table (Zwischenwerte)
Dim rsRec As DAO.recordset     'rs clone of subform Rechenwerte
Dim rstRechenwerte As DAO.recordset
Dim rstZwischenwerte As DAO.recordset
Dim rstZutaten As DAO.recordset
Dim RezeptID As Integer
Dim RechengruppeID As Integer
Dim i As Integer

'Set Current Rezept and Rechengruppe
RezeptID = Me.RezeptID
RechengruppeID = Me.RechengruppeID

'Initialize variables
Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set xlWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Add
Set xlSheet = xlWB.Sheets("Tabelle1") 'Set xlSheet to the first sheet in the workbook
Set rsRes = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("tblTempResults", dbOpenDynaset)
Set rsZwi = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("tblTempZwischenwerte", dbOpenDynaset)
Set rsRec = Me.frmSubRechenwerteBox.Form.recordset.Clone
   
'Disable user input
Call mdlMiscFunctions.DisableKeyboardMouse(True)

'Clear temporary data tables for Results and Zwischenwerte
If Not rsRes.EOF Then Call ClearTableOnClose("tblTempResults")
If Not rsZwi.EOF Then Call ClearTableOnClose("tblTempZwischenwerte")

'Prevent prompt to save changes to excel
xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False
xlApp.Visible = True

' Open the Recordset for tblRechenwerte
Set rstRechenwerte = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT Rechenwert, WertBezeichnung, XLCell FROM tblRechenwerte WHERE RechengruppeID = " & RechengruppeID)

' Insert the values of "Rechenwert" in the cells specified by "XLCell"
rstRechenwerte.MoveFirst
Do Until rstRechenwerte.EOF
    xlSheet.Range(rstRechenwerte!XLCell).Value = rstRechenwerte!WertBezeichnung
    xlSheet.Range(rstRechenwerte!XLCell).Offset(0, 1).Value = rstRechenwerte!Rechenwert
    xlSheet.Range(rstRechenwerte!XLCell).Offset(0, 1).NumberFormat = "0.0000"
    rstRechenwerte.MoveNext
Loop

xlApp.Calculate
xlSheet.Calculate
xlApp.CalculateFull
xlApp.CalculateFullRebuild

rstRechenwerte.Close

' Open the Recordset for tblZwischenwerte
Set rstZwischenwerte = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT ZWBezeichnung, XLFormula, XLCell FROM tblZwischenwerte WHERE RezeptID = " & RezeptID)

' Insert the values of "ZWBezeichnung" in the cells specified by "XLCell"
rstZwischenwerte.MoveFirst
Do Until rstZwischenwerte.EOF
    xlSheet.Range(rstZwischenwerte!XLCell).Value = rstZwischenwerte!ZWBezeichnung
    xlSheet.Range(rstZwischenwerte!XLCell).Offset(0, 1).Formula = rstZwischenwerte!xlFormula
    xlSheet.Range(rstZwischenwerte!XLCell).Offset(0, 1).NumberFormat = "0.0000"
    rstZwischenwerte.MoveNext
Loop

xlApp.Calculate
xlSheet.Calculate
xlApp.CalculateFull
xlApp.CalculateFullRebuild

rstZwischenwerte.Close

' Open the Recordset for tblZutaten
Set rstZutaten = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT Zutat, XLFormula, XLCell FROM tblZutaten WHERE RezeptID = " & RezeptID)

' Insert the values of "Zutat" in the cells specified by "XLCell"
rstZutaten.MoveFirst
Do Until rstZutaten.EOF
    xlSheet.Range(rstZutaten!XLCell).Value = rstZutaten!Zutat
    xlSheet.Range(rstZutaten!XLCell).Offset(0, 1).Formula = rstZutaten!xlFormula
    xlSheet.Range(rstZutaten!XLCell).Offset(0, 1).NumberFormat = "0.0000"
    rstZutaten.MoveNext
Loop

xlApp.Calculate
xlSheet.Calculate
xlApp.CalculateFull
xlApp.CalculateFullRebuild

rstZutaten.Close

'Extract data from excel and insert into tblTempResults
i = 4

Do Until IsEmpty(xlSheet.Range("E" & i).Value)
    rsRes.AddNew
    rsRes!RezepturKomponenten = xlSheet.Range("E" & i).Value
    rsRes!Wert = xlSheet.Range("F" & i).Value
    rsRes.Update
    i = i + 1
Loop

'Extract data from exel and insert into tblTempZwischenwerte
i = 4

Do Until IsEmpty(xlSheet.Range("C" & i).Value)
    rsZwi.AddNew
    rsZwi!Zwischenwert = xlSheet.Range("C" & i).Value
    rsZwi!Wert = xlSheet.Range("D" & i).Value
    rsZwi.Update
    i = i + 1
Loop

'Clean up and close excel
rsRes.Close
rsRec.Close
rsZwi.Close
xlWB.Close SaveChanges:=False
xlApp.Quit

'Release objects from memory
Set xlSheet = Nothing
Set xlWB = Nothing
Set xlApp = Nothing
Set rsRes = Nothing
Set rsZwi = Nothing
Set rsRec = Nothing
Set rstRechenwerte = Nothing
Set rstRechenwerte = Nothing
Set rstZutaten = Nothing

'Refresh the main Form frmClacBatch
DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdRefresh

'Enable user input
Call mdlMiscFunctions.DisableKeyboardMouse(False)

End Sub
```

I still have to clean up the code so its still a work in progress, but most of it should work even if it could probably be simplified a bit.

**Some info on the formats:**

I am always opening a new excel workbook to insert the formulas so all cells are formatted as "standard" by default. I tried setting the format manually before AND after plugging in the formula like so:

```
rstZutaten.MoveFirst
Do Until rstZutaten.EOF
    xlSheet.Range(rstZutaten!XLCell).Value = rstZutaten!Zutat
    xlSheet.Range(rstZutaten!XLCell).Offset(0, 1).NumberFormat = "General"
    xlSheet.Range(rstZutaten!XLCell).Offset(0, 1).Formula = rstZutaten!xlFormula
    rstZutaten.MoveNext
Loop
```

I tried using "General" and some other formats like "0,000" etc. None have any effect.

**The excel file itself after inserting the formulas looks something like this:**

[image: ExcelFile]

The formulas are correct and if I select the cell, click on the formula bar and hit enter, they calculate the value correctly and display that instead. Calculations are set to automatic as per default. I read that there might be issues if the formulas are not in english so I converted them to the english expression like `=SUM(A3,B3:F12)`instead of `=SUMME(A3;B3:F12)`. That did not fix the issue either. The cells I plug the formulas into and the ones I try to extract the values from are correctly specified and are in fact the same cells.

Comment: What is the value of `xlSheet.Range("F" & i).Value` when it fails? What kind of field is `rsRes!Wert`?

Comment: Is `XLCell` a range address? Are the cells where you try dropping the strings correctly updated? If you insert a code line: `Debug.print rstZutaten!XLCell:Stop` just after `Do Until rstZutaten.EOF`, what does it return in `Immediate Window` when stopped on it? Is Excel `Calculations` set to `Automatic`?

Comment: How the range where you paste is initially formatted? As `Text`? If so, try `xlSheet.Range(rstZutaten!XLCell).Offset(0, 1).value = xlSheet.Range(rstZutaten!XLCell).Offset(0, 1).value`. It may look strange, but it will do the job in such a case... Of course, if Calculations are on `Automatic`. Otherwise, you should also use `xlSheet.Calculate`.

Comment: If the cell is formatted as text and you insert a formula then it will read it as text and that would explain why you see the expression. Clear the format of the cell before insterting the formula (make it Standard), insert your formula, copy/paste as value and then apply your desired format and try again.

Comment: updated the question to address some of the comments.

Comment: @FaneDuru was right. The format was not set to text but 'standard' before inserting the formulas but I suppose that changed once they were plugged in and setting it correctly after did not update much really? Using `xlSheet.Range(rstZutaten!XLCell).Offset(0, 1).value = xlSheet.Range(rstZutaten!XLCell).Offset(0, 1).value` after plugging in the formula did fix it once I had converted them to use the english notation. No idea why though. I assume it just re-enters the content and that seemingly updates the cell correctly. Anyway, the code now runs fine, so Thx!

Comment: I think your problem is in this line  xlSheet.Range(rstZutaten!XLCell).Offset(0, 1).Formula = rstZutaten!xlFormula  you should change it to xlSheet.Range(rstZutaten!XLCell).Offset(0, 1).Formula = Chr(34) & "=" &  rstZutaten!xlFormula & Chr(34)